# Alguien que me ayude, nadie sabe darme respuesta a que debo hacer? ya llevo demasiados buscando y nada funciona

Tags: mysql-workbench, localhost, autenticación, host

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de verdad que me duele la cabeza de tanto leer y no encontrar nada. gracias a los que lean esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenid@, por favor lee [ask], te recomiendo edites y coloques un título objetivo y relacionado al problema en cuestión así como una descripción con una estructura que le permita a la comunidad identificar el posible problema y te puedan ayudar

Comment: Parece que el problema ocurre al intentar iniciar el servicio... ¿es posible que el puerto 3306 ya esté siendo usado por otro servicio?
Abre una ventana de símbolo del sistema como administrador y ejecuta el comando "netstat –ab", aparecerá la lista de puertos usados, mira a ver si ya esta usando el 3306.